# Searching for a word in a column made of sentences

Tags: python, string, sqlite

I'm using SQLite3 with python in JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.4.

I have a table that looks like this. ID is integer, name and content are text.

```
ID Name Content
1  Matt oirefasd aifsfnib if ib @John sefuhrg wefirwgf
2  John sdfwre frwgfwg wegfhtr @Patsfrwg
3  Pat  asjgre wurgjnsow wouregjeo @Johnsfbwufaeovnwo
4  John sfgoe eriogner weogfib
```

So here is my question,
Assume a user John, is logged in. How do I write the sqlite query such that I receive the rows that contain messages starting with @ symbol followed by the user that is logged in (John) in the Content column.

I should receive the answer as a tuple.(ID, Name, Content)

So the solution should be:

```
ID Name Content
1  Matt oirefasd aifsfnib if ib @John sefuhrg wefirwgf
3  Pat  asjgre wurgjnsow wouregjeo @Johnsfbwufaeovnwo
```

This is my current sql query. currentuser stores the name of the current logged in user in this case John.

```
str = '%'+ currentuser + '%'
c = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT id, Name, content FROM myusers WHERE myusers.content LIKE ? LiMIT ?"
c.execute(sql,(str,limit))
return [x[0] for x in c]
```

I keep getting an error which says "'int' object is not subscriptable"

This code above was getting tested against my unit test statement. This statement is:

```
self.assertListEqual([1, 3], [a[0] for a in posts])
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the `x` values to see what they are? That should explain why you're getting this error.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm new to python. I tried using a loop to print all the values but Jetbrains IDE doesn't allow me to print from a .py file.

Comment: What do you mean "Jetbrains IDE doesn't allow me to print from a .py file"? PyCharm definitely lets you `print`. It also lets you set breakpoints in the integrated debugger, write to a file, and a million other things. And if you don't learn how to do at least one of those things, you're never going to be able to debug anything, which means you'll never be able to code anything.

Comment: So this is what i did "for x in c:
                                     print(x,c[x])"   and the error was "'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: OK, what about when you do `from x in c: print(x)`?

Comment: So if this was any other language, i wouldn't be here. But I don't know this dude, that why I'm asking.

Comment: Also, why did you even try to print `c[x]`? `c` is the cursor; `x` is the row; what would `c[x]` mean?

Comment: Meanwhile, I just tested your code (which would be easier if you gave us the SQL to generate and populate the table instead of just describing it, but I doubt there are any significant differences between mine and yours), and it returns `[1, 3]`. Are you sure this is exactly what you're doing in your real code?

Comment: i tried what you suggested. The Run window at the bottom  says "Process finished with exit code 0". I think this works but where do I look for the values it printed?

Comment: I don't remember where the menu item is, but the easiest thing to do is to set the Debug Window to "Console" instead of whatever other tool it's set to, and it'll show you the stdout there.

Comment: I just installed PyCharm, and with the default settings, the first time you run a project, it switches to the Console tab automatically. The output of your program comes directly above the "Process finished with exit code 0".

Comment: I just noticed that you tagged this MySQL. Which one are you using? Because your code is correct for sqlite3, but not for any of the major MySQL libraries.

Comment: You said, it went to Console tab. If you look at the bottom it says "Run" and "Debug". So when I run my .py file it open up the Run console and shows the follow message "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: One last thing: please show the entire exception, with traceback, instead of just describing the error. Are you sure it's even this line that's raising the exception? (The fact that adding a `print` doesn't seem to show any output implies it's not even getting this far.)

Comment: The entire exception says "self.assertListEqual([1, 3], [p[0] for p in posts])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" 

I am using unit tests to check whether I return a list with [1 and 3] rows. In this case it doesnt do that

Comment: Put that into your question, not in a comment. And also show the code that includes that line, because it's _that_ code that's wrong, not the code you showed us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully, I was asked to return tuples.
AND
If you look at the unit testing statement `assertListEqual([1, 3], [a[0] for a in posts])` it means that you are comparing the values of the two lists.

Therefore the solution lies in the code that was provided with the question.

Instead of using this

```
return [x[0] for x in c]
```

which returns the first element of each row. I use this statement:

```
return [x for x in c]
```

This returns the tuples.

Now when the assert statement applies to the tuples which return the a[0] element for two tuples and in this case it is [1,3]. The test passes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a line like this:

```
self.assertListEqual([1, 3], [p[0] for p in posts])
```

That isn't in any of the code you showed us. But presumably, `posts` is the list returned by the code in your question. And `posts` is a list of integers, like `[1, 3]`, so each `p` is an integer, so each `p[0]` is going to raise an exception, because you're asking for `1[0]`, which makes no sense.

I think you just want `assertListEqual([1, 3], posts)`.

Comment: Give me some time to check this and ill get back to you